# Length of data() parameter in first TR of a table is "undefined" at click but not at further TRs

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am having a table

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="msctrans_navtree">

            <tr class="msctrans_navrow" data-subs="603" data-navlevel="1" data-sp_id="2" data-standardsprache="1">
                <td><strong>Test</strong></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2">List of documents</td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="msctrans_navrow" data-subs="" data-navlevel="1" data-sp_id="2" data-standardsprache="1">
                <td><strong>Test 1</strong></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2">List of documents 1</td>
            </tr>
<tr class="msctrans_navrow" data-subs="334,23,5,21" data-navlevel="1" data-sp_id="2" data-standardsprache="1">
                <td><strong>Test 2</strong></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="2">List of documents 2</td>
            </tr>
```

Clicking on the TR with class "msctrans_navrow" should do something regarding the data parameters of the clicked element:

```
$(".msctrans_navrow").click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var subs = clicked.data("subs");
    var navlevel = clicked.data("navlevel");
    var sp_id = clicked.data("sp_id");
    var spstandard = clicked.data("standardsprache");
    alert(subs + " = " + subs.length);
    // Action only if there are subs
    if (subs.length) {
        clicked.toggleClass("mscajaxloaderdivabsolut");
        var insertAfter = clicked.next();
        alert("Now I am doing some Ajax and inert it after the inserAfter element.");
    }
});
```

Unfortunately when clicking the first TR where the data-subs parameters value is 603 subs.length in the script delivers an "undefined". I can't figure why that is.

Here is a fiddle to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/9B9AW/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's stored as a number, not a string, inside jQuery's data cache for that element. Numbers don't have a `length` property. You could force a conversion to string by calling `.toString()`:

```
if(subs.toString().length) {
    // code if the string representation of `subs` has a length > 0
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `.attr()` method instead, which won't convert (always retrieves the value as a string):

```
var subs = clicked.attr("data-subs");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `var subs = clicked.data("subs");`

to `var subs = ""+clicked.data("subs");` `// make it a String`

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/9B9AW/10/

Comment: You are doing the same as Anthony. Works as well. Thank you.